# Set OSX as default start up disk from Windows using command line

Tags: windows, macos, command-line, automation, bootcamp

I've installed Windows 7 using Bootcamp on Mac. I want to automatically choosing different startup boot partition on either Mac or Windows using a command line from Terminal or Command Prompt. From Mac, I am able to use Terminal to choose boot partition between OSX and Windows 7 using "setboot". Is there a way that I can do the same on Windows partition? After setting Windows as default startup disk and boot into Windows, I need to be able to set Mac as a default startup disk from Windows so that when I restart the machine using a script, it will automatically boot into Mac...

I've looked at the settings under "msconfig" and using "list volume from diskpart", it doesn't list the OSX partition and I cannot open the boot.ini using bootcfg... Would that means Windows doesn't "know" there is a Mac partition at all?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps? :
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110602112643936

It uses AutoIt, which is free, and resorts to ui automation in Windows (which may or may not be desirable to you). I haven't tested this, but when I saw your post, I thought about AutoIt, which I've found to be very powerful and useful.